# Update and save records in a django.db.models.query.QuerySet object?

Tags: django, set, models

In django when dealng with model objects consider the following:

```
>>> x = table.objects.all()
>>> x[0].coulomb1
'hello'
>>>
>>> x[0].coulomb1 = 'goodbye'
>>>
>>> x[0].coulomb1
'hello'
```

Please can you help me understand how to change this value and save it?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
I managed it with:

```
>>> x
[<table: table object>]
>>> y = x[0]
>>> y
<table: table object>
>>> y.coulomb1 = 'goodbye'
>>> y.coulomb1
'goodbye'
>>> y.save()
>>>
>>> x[0].coulomb1
'goodbye'
```

Would be nice if someone could explain why it didn't work whilst within the queryset though.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table.objects.all()` is a `django.query.QuerySet object`. When you run `x[0]`, you actually calls its `__getitem__` method.

You can find its implementation at [github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/753a22a6352638b7df55176584795ac8c5d4232c/django/db/models/query.py).

Below is a simplified version. I only remove the safety check and slice code.

```
def __getitem__(self, k):
    """
    Retrieves an item or slice from the set of results.
    """
    if self._result_cache is not None:
        return self._result_cache[k]

    qs = self._clone()
    qs.query.set_limits(k, k + 1)
    return list(qs)[0]
```

You see, when the queryset is **not** cached, each time you run `queryset[index]`, it triggers a new sql query and returns a new object.